# How to move a phrase in a resume template?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, resume

Here is some template CV in LaTeX: http://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/
Consider [template number 9a](http://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/res9a.pdf) ([source](http://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/res9a.tex)).
I want to move the name to the left, write "Resume" in the middle, and put a date on the right.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
% Center the name over the entire width of resume:
 \moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{\large\bf Susan R. Bumpershoot}
```

use the following for your resume header:

```
% Name on left, RESUME, date right
\hspace*{-\hoffset}{\large\bfseries\rlap{Susan R. Bumpershoot} \hfill%
RE\'SUM\'E \hfill%
\llap{\today}\par}
```

`\rlap` and `\llap` sets the name/date in a zero-width box to ensure that `RESUME` is centred.

[image]

You may also wish to adjust the width of the horizontal rule as I've done in the above image, since it's slightly wider than the text width:

```
% Name on left, RESUME, date right
\hspace*{-\hoffset}{\large\bfseries\rlap{Susan R. Bumpershoot} \hfill%
R\'ESUM\'E \hfill%
\llap{\today}\par}\kern-\parskip
% Draw a horizontal line the whole width of resume:
\hspace*{-\hoffset}\vbox{\hrule width\dimexpr\textwidth+\hoffset\relax height 1pt}\par\smallskip
```

As a suggestion, other (more modern) resume/CV templates/packages/classes exist. Consider, for example, using the [`moderncv` document class](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv).